# Promise return is inconsistent React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, promise

I am using a library that calls an API, and I am waiting for Promise return to receive an Array.
However, even though I expect 2 elements in ActivityItem array, sometimes I receive only first of them (the one that appears first (Item1). From my point of view, I implemented the Promise incorrectly and there should be a mistake in the way I return them, but I miss seeing it.
Here I call the function that uses that should return Promise:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.getDataFromKit(ONEDAYINTERVAL).then(result => {
    this.sendDataToServer(result); //sending to backend
    }).catch(e => console.error);
}
```

And here is a method itself:

```
getDataFromKit(dateFrom) {

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
    AppleKit.initKit(KitPermissions.uploadBasicKitData(), (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            return;
        }

    AppleKit.getSamples(dateFrom, (err, results) => {
                if (err) {
                    return resolve([]);
                }
                const newData = results.map(item => {
                    return { ...item, name: "Item1" };
                });
                const allData = [...this.state.ActivityItem, ...newData];
                this.setState({ ActivityItem: allData });
                resolve(allData);
            });


        // if I delete the code below it will work just fine always grabbing only one item.
        new Promise((resolve) => { 
        AppleKit.getSamplesSecondMethod(dateFrom, (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                return resolve([]);
            }
            const newData = results.map(item => {
                return { ...item, name: "Item2" };
            });
            const allData = [...this.state.ActivityItem, ...newData];
            this.setState({ ActivityItem: allData });
            resolve(allData);
             });
           });
        }); 
    })
}
```

The main issue here is I guess: how can I return multiple promises from this one method?

Comment: Use `Promise.all(array_of_promises)`. It returns a Promise that when all promises in the array have resolved, resolves to an array of the results, in the same order.

Comment: Can you give an example how I can use it in my case?

Comment: Inside the initKit Promise, use `return Promise.all( [new Promise(...), new Promise(...)] ).then(resolve);`

Comment: got it, but how can I differ those two Promises that I have? I mean assigning it to a variable doesn't work

Comment: Here's example code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/aL8tcpzo/ The resulting array contains the results of the promises, in order

Comment: What you want to do is return any downstream async promise call without an attached `.then`  method.  Does that make sense or should I re-write your code and put it in an answer?

Comment: @BrianPatterson would appreciate a lot if you can put it  in the answer, I am a bit confused with would this means practically

Comment: @VladDemyan I posted an answer, can you try the code and let me know if it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as I see it, is your second block of code doesn't get run because you are resolving the promise in the first block.   The way you have it coded, you will want to resolve that promise only once all your async operations have completed.   I modified your code, but have not tested it.   It may need to add the `.then` method to make sure the async data is returned before resolving the initial promise.

What happens if you try this ?

**UPDATE**

It looks like the below code solved your problem as you accepted my answer.   However, I did re-write it before I realized you accepted so I will add the new updated code in case that will help you or someone else.

**Original Answer**

```
getDataFromKit(dateFrom) {

    const thenable = new Promise((resolve) => {
            AppleKit.initKit(KitPermissions.uploadBasicKitData(), (err, results) => {
                if (err) {
                    return;
                }


                AppleKit.getSamples(dateFrom, (err, results) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return resolve([]);
                    }
                    const newData = results.map(item => {
                        return {
                            ...item,
                            name: "Item1"
                        };
                    });

                    resolve(newData);

                });
            });
        })
        .then((newData) => {

            AppleKit.initKit(KitPermissions.uploadBasicKitData(), (err, results) => {
                if (err) {
                    return;
                }


                AppleKit.getSamplesSecondMethod(dateFrom, (err, results) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return;
                    }

                    var stateData = this.state.ActivityItem;

                    const addData = results.map(item => {
                        return {
                            ...item,
                            name: "Item2"
                        };
                    });
                    stateData = [...stateData, ...newData];
                    stateData = [...stateData, ...addData];

                    this.setState({
                        ActivityItem: stateData
                    });

                });


            });
        });
    return thenable;
}
```

**Updated Code using Promise.all**

```
getDataFromKit(dateFrom) {

    return new Promise((resolve) => {

        const promise1 = new Promise((resolve) => {
            AppleKit.initKit(KitPermissions.uploadBasicKitData(), (err, results) => {
                if (err) {
                    return Promise.reject(err);
                }


                AppleKit.getSamples(dateFrom, (err, results) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return Promise.reject(err);
                    }
                    const newData = results.map(item => {
                        return {
                            ...item,
                            name: "Item1"
                        };
                    });

                    return Promise.resolve(newData);

                });
            });
        });

        const promise2 = new Promise((resolve) => {

            AppleKit.initKit(KitPermissions.uploadBasicKitData(), (err, results) => {
                if (err) {
                    return Promise.reject(err);
                }


                AppleKit.getSamplesSecondMethod(dateFrom, (err, results) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return Promise.reject(err);
                    }

                    const moreData = results.map(item => {
                        return {
                            ...item,
                            name: "Item2"
                        };
                    });

                    return Promise.resolve(moreData);
                });
            });
        });


        Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
            .then(([result1, result2]) => {

                var nArrays = [result1, result2, this.state.ActivityItem];

                const finalResult = [].concat(...nArrays);

                return Promise.resolve(finalResult);

            });    
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I'll try to update the code and run it in a couple of hours! Will let you know then.

Comment: OK, updated the answer, can you try that and let me know how it goes ?

Comment: Ok, i've tried a couple of things around with this code but it seems like code is not executing at all. I mean the request is not send thought ComponentDidMount, and when I do it through the button the size of  ActivityItem is 0 (which I guess is also because code is not executing). Also no console.logs are showing

Comment: Ok sorry, that was my fault. Actually I got 'Can't find variable resolve', I will try to fix that now

Comment: I took the calls to resolve out of the .then method.   That should hopefully take care of that error.   Can you try the updated code.